# HttpRequestMessage won't allow Authorization header value

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient

I'm trying to reuse my `HttpClient` instance, as that's best practice.
 Therefore, in one particular request, I want to set the `Authorization` header on the request, instead of setting it globally on the client. From everything I've read, this ought to work:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
var response = await _client.SendAsync(request);
```

This compiles, but then throws when I attempt to call it. The exception I get is:

> "Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with
>   HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and
>   content headers with HttpContent objects."

I'm confused why I'm allowed to set this value on the request message if it's just going to throw, and I also haven't figured out a workaround.
I've tried directly adding the header using `TryAddWithoutValidation` but I still get the same exception (not even a return of false like I'd expect!)

I'm suspecting this might be a bug in the framework since multiple people have posted this exact code with no apparent problems, but would be interested in any insights/workarounds.

Comment: does the client already have a default authorization header set?

Comment: It does not--I'm trying to avoid setting one because we're reusing this client in multiple places

Comment: Which line exactly throws the error. Send or when you set the header?

Comment: When I attempt to set the header. It throws the same error whether I directly set request.Headers.Authorization or use Headers.Add() or Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation()

Comment: Ok going to dig up in the source code to see whats happening when that property is set

Comment: @Nkosi never mind--it turns out my actual access token was null and I didn't realize because the error message was giving me the completely wrong idea of the problem. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Ok. Glad to help. I would suggest deleting the question then.

Comment: I'm gonna leave it up in case anyone else has this issue. The error message is very misleading.

Comment: Ok noted. Were you checking the bool result of `TryAddWithoutValidation` to see if it returned true?

Comment: It threw an exception without returning anything--I assume there's still validation to make sure the header value is correctly formed. And I appreciate that validation, but an accurate error message would have made this whole situation much simpler

Comment: Understood and totally agree. suggest raising an issue on the repo, if one has not been done already

Comment: Will do! Do you happen to know where the repo lives? I looked before and couldn't find it.

Comment: Check here https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.Net.Http

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that due to a different bug, the value of "token" was null. I would recommend checking this first if you're having this issue: note that the error message was 100% a lie.